# Navigation causes crash after opening killed activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation, android-navigation

My app crashes after restarting killed activity that uses multiple back stack as shown in [samples](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt) for bottom navigation tabs. It only crashes when using multistack.

Stacktrace:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.downEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:263)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.backwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:314)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:334)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:145)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.setCurrentState(LifecycleRegistry.java:118)
    at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.updateState(NavBackStackEntry.java:150)
    at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.setMaxLifecycle(NavBackStackEntry.java:130)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.popBackStackInternal(NavController.java:325)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.dispatchOnDestinationChanged(NavController.java:426)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:636)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:586)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:551)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:247)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2867)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:444)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1287)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1444)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1522)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1575)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3001)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2938)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate(FragmentController.java:240)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:243)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:118)
    at my.base.ui.base.DaggerActivity.onCreate(DaggerActivity.kt:26)
    at my.base.ui.base.delegate.LocalizationActivity.onCreate(LocalizationActivity.kt:29)
    at my.base.ui.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:34)
    at my.base.ui.base.BaseFragNavActivity.onCreate(BaseFragNavActivity.kt:37)
    at my.app.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:40)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
    ... 10 more
```

Line where it throws the exception:

```
private static Event downEvent(State state) {
        switch (state) {
            case INITIALIZED:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

Dependencies:

```
const val navigationFragment = "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0"
const val navigationUi = "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0"
```

Setup code:

```
binding.bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(
            listOf(
                R.navigation.nav1,
                R.navigation.nav2,
                R.navigation.nav3
            ),
            supportFragmentManager,
            R.id.container,
            intent
        ).observe(this) { controller ->
            navController = controller
            controller.addOnDestinationChangedListener(this)
        }
```

Xml (tried with `<fragment/>` too):

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

[Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161825212) (has a reproducible sample)

Comment: "*I couldn't reproduce it with a clean app yet, as I'm not sure why it's happening*" - that means that you failed to isolate the problem. Try to paste more and more code and, when you find that the problem appears again, try to reduce the code again.

Comment: look here `at my.base.ui.base.DaggerActivity.onCreate(DaggerActivity.kt:26)
    at my.base.ui.base.delegate.LocalizationActivity.onCreate(LocalizationActivity.kt:29)
    at my.base.ui.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:34)
    at my.base.ui.base.BaseFragNavActivity.onCreate(BaseFragNavActivity.kt:37)
    at my.app.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:40)`

Comment: @IR42 I already did

Comment: @Fureeish I was able to reproduce it at last, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161825212

Comment: Please paste the [mre] in the question, not as an external link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the problem was having the same id for navigation graphs and destinations. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161825212